# Nuxt.js: Renderer resources are not loaded! Please check possible console errors and ensure dist

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, iisnode

On my Nuxt staging site this error occurs:

```
NuxtServerError
Renderer resources are not loaded! Please check possible console errors and ensure dist (C:\Users\xyz\.nuxt\dist\server) exists.
```

There are no console errors - only '500 error' for the page.

I've upgraded Node from 8.16.0 to 10.23.2. While developing locally no issues occurs. For building the site locally I'm using `cross-env NODE_ENV=development nuxt`. For the staging build `cross-env NODE_ENV=staging nuxt build --standalone`.

I can even replicate the above error locally if I setup an IIS site in a separate folder.

I've copied these files/folders: `.nuxt`, `static`, `node_modules`, `nuxt.config.js`, `server.js` and `web.config`. The site is using [IISNode](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode).

After copying the files I've verified that `/.nuxt/dist` actually exists. But after getting the error above the `/.nuxt/dist` folder disappears and also an `/assets` folder is generated (which usually doesnt happen for other sites I've worked on?).

The IISNode log contains:

```
(node:692) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

 WARN  No pages directory found in C:\Users\xyz. Using the default built-in page.
(node:692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not compile template C:\\Users\\xyz\\node_modules\\@nuxt\\vue-app\\template\\App.js: Cannot resolve "@assets/scss/main.scss" from "C:\Users\xyz\assets\scss\main.scss"
    at Promise.all.templateFiles.map (C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\@nuxt\builder\dist\builder.js:6018:17)
(node:692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:692) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've tried:

```
npm clean cache
npm node_modules -r
npm package-lock.json
npm install 
npm rebuild node-sass
```

I'm wondering if some kind third party package is running a clean up task. ESlint, Stylelint?

Answer (score 0):

In web.config `node_env` was set to `staging`:

```
<iisnode
  node_env="staging"
  ...
/>
```

But in server.js I was testing for `production`, which caused staging to build like development:

```
// ...

config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'); // <============

async function start () {
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
  // Start build process in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
    builder.build();
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready();
  }

  // ...
}

// ...
```

Changed it to:

```
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
```